# Fragment getArguments() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` which has a `TabHost` as the root layout as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <!-- More FrameLayouts here - each are placeholders for Fragments -->    

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The code to create / update each `Fragment` for the tab content is as follows...

```
private void updateTab(String tabId, int placeholder) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt("current_day", mCurrentTab);
        EpgEventListFragment fragment = new EpgEventListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(placeholder, new EpgEventListFragment(), tabId)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

In the `onCreate(...)` method of the `EpgEventListFragment` I then try to get the arguments `Bundle` but I always get `null` doing the following...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments == null)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Arguments is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        mCurrentDay = getArguments().getInt("current_day", 0);

    ...
}
```

What am I missing here? I also tried `getArguments()` in `onAttach(...)` but I still got null. I'm new to using `Fragments` so I'm hoping there's a simple reason but I haven't come up with anything when searching.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I'm thinking this has to do with your problem:

```
fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(placeholder, new EpgEventListFragment(), tabId)
    .commit();
```

You're making a new `Fragment` (that doesn't have arguments since it's been freshly instantiated).

Instead try

```
Fragment fragment = new EpgEventListFragment();
fragment.setArguments(arguments);
fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(placeholder, fragment, tabId)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Oh you have got to be kidding me...aaaargh!

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is another pair of eyes. Thank you! I wasn't originally passing arguments so I was creating the `Fragment` in the call to `replace(...)`. There's a time delay for me to accept your answer but I'll do so. Thanks again.

Comment: @Squonk you're welcome! I recall one time I forgot to extend `FragmentActivity`. It was the best half hour of my life trying to figure that out :-)

Comment: Created a new instance of the fragment added arguments then at the return statement I did this "return new CompaniesFragment()" -_-