# java.lang.NullPointerException error only from Galaxy samsung

Tags: java, android

I received some reports of this error, but I have test equipment and everything goes right. Strange is that all error reports are sent from mobile samsung.
Any idea what could be if I can not resolve it?
error code:

```
Último informe
18 de jun. 4:57
Informes de esta semana
1
Informes totales
1
Versión de la aplicación

25
1
Versión de Android

Android 5.1
1
Dispositivo
Galaxy S6 Edge+ (zenlte) 1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.TorrentPlayerFragment$1.onClick(TorrentPlayerFragment.java:107)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10557)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21203)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Java:

```
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class TorrentPlayerFragment  extends Fragment  implements TorrentListener {


    private Button button2;
    private Button button;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TorrentStream torrentStream;

    String mStreamUrl;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_torrent_player_fragment, container, false);


        mStreamUrl = ((EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.bTorrentUrl)).getText().toString();

        String action = getActivity().getIntent().getAction();
        Uri data = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
        if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) && data != null) {
            try {
                mStreamUrl = URLDecoder.decode(data.toString(), "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        TorrentOptions torrentOptions = new TorrentOptions.Builder()
                .saveLocation(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))
                .removeFilesAfterStop(true)
                .build();

        torrentStream = TorrentStream.init(torrentOptions);
        torrentStream.addListener(this);

        button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        progressBar.setMax(100);



        return v;


    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            if(torrentStream.isStreaming()) {
                torrentStream.stopStream();
                button.setText("Start stream");
                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return;
            }
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            mStreamUrl  = args.getString("url");
            torrentStream.startStream(mStreamUrl);
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setText("Stop stream");
        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onStreamPrepared(Torrent torrent) {
        Log.d("Torrent", "OnStreamPrepared");
        torrent.startDownload();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStreamStarted(Torrent torrent) {
        Log.d("Torrent", "onStreamStarted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStreamError(Torrent torrent, Exception e) {
        Log.e("Torrent", "onStreamError", e);
        button.setText("Start stream");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStreamReady(Torrent torrent) {
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
        Log.d("Torrent", "onStreamReady: " + torrent.getVideoFile());


        final String UrlFinalTorrent = torrent.getVideoFile().toString();

        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", UrlFinalTorrent);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onStreamProgress(Torrent torrent, StreamStatus status) {
        if(status.bufferProgress <= 100 && progressBar.getProgress() < 100 && progressBar.getProgress() != status.bufferProgress) {
            Log.d("Torrent", "Progress: " + status.bufferProgress);
            progressBar.setProgress(status.bufferProgress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStreamStopped() {
        Log.d("Torrent", "onStreamStopped");
    }
}
```

I think the problem comes from here:

```
        final String UrlFinalTorrent = torrent.getVideoFile().toString();

    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", UrlFinalTorrent);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

but as I said I tried everything on android devices and on the emulator and things are working. But this error appears on Samsung devices.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack trace seems pretty clearly to point to the anonymous inner class instantiated for variable `mOnClickListener`.  This is the first inner class, in source order, appearing in class `TorrentPlayerFragment` (as indicated by the stack trace), and it contains an invocation of the method reported as throwing the NPE: `android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)`.  Specifically,

```
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            mStreamUrl  = args.getString("url");
```

It seems pretty likely that `getArguments()` is returning `null` in the affected environment.  This seems related to [Android Fragment getArguments() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561817/android-fragment-getarguments-returns-null), but I cannot be confident that the circumstances or solutions are the same.

Comment: please excuse me with my questions. Why certain things are working android devices? And what do you recommend? replace bundle?

Comment: @DiaconuLiviu, I cannot be certain what is the best solution for your particular situation, because the larger scope is unclear.  The answers to the other SO question I linked have some advice that you should consider, however.

Comment: I solved a string url was not valid, java wrong pages each.