# Stuck on Android.os.Bundle with Null Object Reference

Tags: java, android

I don't know why this error happens. I have checked all the code that link to this one but still doesn't give any solution.

The IDE just gimme error like this :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>                                                                      at com.gook.rebill.fragment.HomeFragment.onAttach(HomeFragment.java:74)

I know it's a null object reference, but still i don't get where the cause of error.

Please help me.

this is my **code** :

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements InternetConnectionListener, ApiHandler.ApiHandlerListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private final int CATEGORY_ACTION = 1;
    private CategorySelectionCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
    private ListView categoryListView;
    private String Error = null;
    private InternetConnectionListener internetConnectionListener;

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((HomeActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        try {
            mCallbacks = (CategorySelectionCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement CategorySelectionCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        categoryListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (UtilMethods.isConnectedToInternet(getActivity())) {
            initCategoryList();
        } else {
            internetConnectionListener = (InternetConnectionListener) HomeFragment.this;
            showNoInternetDialog(getActivity(), internetConnectionListener,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_text),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.retry_string),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.exit_string), CATEGORY_ACTION);
        }

    }

    public class getCategList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            /**
             * json is populating from text file. To make api call use ApiHandler class
             *
             *  <CODE>ApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiHandler(this, URL_GET_CATEGORY);</CODE> <BR>
             *  <CODE>apiHandler.doApiRequest(ApiHandler.REQUEST_GET);</CODE> <BR>
             *
             * You will get the response in onSuccessResponse(String tag, String jsonString) method
             * if successful api call has done. Do the parsing as the following.
             */
            URL hp = null;
            try {
                hp = new URL(
                        getString(R.string.liveurl) + "foodcategory.php");

                Log.d("URL", "" + hp);
                URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
                hpCon.connect();
                InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                String x = "";
                x = r.readLine();
                String total = "";

                while (x != null) {
                    total += x;
                    x = r.readLine();
                }
                Log.d("UR1L", "" + total);

                JSONArray j = new JSONArray(total);

                Log.d("URL1", "" + j.length());



                categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();

                for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                    Category category = new Category();// buat variabel category
                    JSONObject Obj;
                    Obj = j.getJSONObject(i); //sama sperti yang lama, cman ini lebih mempersingkat karena getJSONObject cm d tulis sekali aja disini

                    category.setId(Obj.getString(JF_ID));
                    category.setTitle(Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));
                    category.setIconUrl(Obj.getString(JF_ICON));

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Obj.getString(JF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE))) {
                        category.setImageUrl(Obj.getString(JF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE));
                    }
                    Log.d("URL1",""+Obj.getString(JF_TITLE));
                    categoryList.add(category);
                }

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        categoryListView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mCallbacks, categoryList));
                    }
                });



            }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Error = e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Error = e.getMessage();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Error = e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Error = e.getMessage();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



    //! function for populate category list
    private void initCategoryList() {
            new getCategList().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionEstablished(int code) {
        if (code == CATEGORY_ACTION) {
            initCategoryList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserCanceled(int code) {
        if (code == CATEGORY_ACTION) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    //! catch json response from here
    @Override
    public void onSuccessResponse(String tag, String jsonString) {
        //! do same parsing as done in initCategoryList()
    }

    //! detect response error here
    @Override
    public void onFailureResponse(String tag) {

    }

    //! callback interface listen by HomeActivity to detect user click on category
    public static interface CategorySelectionCallbacks {
        void onCategorySelected(String catID, String title);
    }
}
```

Here where I use the fragment code, in HomeActivity:

```
 public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you create `HomeFragment ` instance? Show the code, plz

Comment: You're probably not using your newInstance method for creating it

Comment: Do you mean show my HomeActivity Code sir @TungD.Nguyen?

Comment: We don't need the whole code but the snippet of where you create and use `HomeFragment`, possibly somewhere in `HomeActivity`

Comment: I have edited the question and add the snippet.

Comment: @AdolfKohel, Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: yes sir, but still getting error @HirenPatel

Answer (score 1):

I think `getArguments()` return null.
You can see these example:
[Android Fragment getArguments() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561817/android-fragment-getarguments-returns-null)
[Fragment getArguments() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970790/fragment-getarguments-returns-null)

Comment: yes sir, i think so. But i have read that and still don't get the error on my code...

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have attached, it appears to happen here.

```
        hp = new URL(
                getString(R.string.liveurl) + "foodcategory.php");
```

Question is - what is R. Can R be null while you are trying to access string.liveurl? This seems to be the likely problem. Can you use debugger to check what is R?

Comment: i think isn't there sir because when i remove that line still got the error

Answer (score 0):

You should do in this way:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (CategorySelectionCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement CategorySelectionCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    categoryListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoryListView);
    return rootView;
}

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
```

**Edit 1:**

You should replace HomeFragment by this way:

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance(my_int); 
_viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(homeFragment,"Home");
```

**Reason:** Simply you were creating **instance** of  `Fragment` by default constructor instead of **instance** with `Arguments`.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I still got an error sir.. now on _ ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));_

Comment: @AdolfKohel, can you please show me that how you are replacing HomeFragment ?

Comment: Okay sir, i'll edit my question for you.. Please help me sir

Comment: Sir, when i delete this line _viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"Home");_ the code will work. But i need these line to make sliding tab view. Can you help me how to fix it?

Comment: @Adolf Kohel, you need to add this way. HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance (my_int); _viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(homeFragment,"Home");

Comment: @AdolfKohel, I have edited my answer with Edit 1 tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallbacks = (CategorySelectionCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement CategorySelectionCallbacks.");
    }
}


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
}
```